# manifest merger failed with multiple errors12

Tags: java, android, import

I am trying to sync my project but am getting an error that manifest merger failed with multiple errors. I have tried all that I know.I am a beginner in this.
I have also posted my build.gradle below. Kindly help me figure out where my problem could be or which code I could have missed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.robertgk.tapchat">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
            </provider>
        </application>



    </manifest>

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.robertgk.tapchat"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:1.+@aar'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try to remove android:allowBackup="true" from app tag

Comment: @Robert Ashioya, Please display a logcat error here..

Comment: hi Divyesh I have removed android:allowBackup but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Put the words in the front

```
*apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'*
```

---

just like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: No, don’t... `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services’` is supposed to go at the very end of your `build.gradle` file. It says right here on the firebase quick start page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Answer (score 0):

I has the same question like you said,here is the solution in my products:

In your manifest file

step 1:

```
<manifest package="com.example.robertgk.tapchat"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

step 2:

```
 <application
     ....
      tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:label"/>
```

step 3： reBuild your project。
Just like this,you can put any attributes what make the multiple error happen into “tools:replac”。

Hope it helps you :)